# Jetpack Compose - best way to handle pixel-exact composables with pointer input

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

Jetpack Compose seems specialized for UI that is positioned and sized automatically, relative to the rest of the UI, without needing to know its exact size. This is great in many cases, but I have a few applications where I need a composable to draw at exact pixel coordinates and sizes. I also need to to track pointer input on the composable, as a percentage of the composable's size.

[image]

The specific case I'm working on now is displaying a piano keyboard, shown in the picture, where each key needs to be sized and placed at specific positions relative to the keyboard as a whole. Also, I need to track the pointers within the keyboard and calculate which keys are pressed. I'm currently implementing it using a Canvas composable. It's helpful that the canvas provides you with its size, but I can't use that size outside the scope of the Canvas for use in tracking the pointer input. This is my plan as of now.

```
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .pointerInput(width, height) {
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                 /* track pointers and calculate which
                 keys are pressed using the values of
                 width and height */
            }
        }.onSizeChanged {
            width = it.width
            height = it.height
        }
    ) {
        /* draw the piano keys, using the values
        of size.width and size.height to size and
        position them */
    }
```

My questions are:

1. The use of the .onSizeChanged modifier to keep track of the size seems janky. Is there a better way? I'm also worried that doing it this way will lead to bugs when the pointerInput scope is cancelled and restarted on a change in size, which could lead to some pointer events being lost.
2. Is it generally acceptable to render a larger UI component, like a piano keyboard, entirely using the canvas? I will have animations for key presses, and using a canvas means the entire keyboard will be redrawn on every frame of the animations. Is it common to manually implement some kind of buffer or caching to avoid redrawing components, or is drawing a bunch of simple shapes just so fast that it generally doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you don't assign any size `Modifier` to `Canvas` the `size` you get from `DrawScope` will have 0 width and height. In Jetpack Compose as long as you don't need this size param you can draw anywhere without setting it but if you check the log you will see that it will have zero width and height.

1- You don't need `onSizeChanged` because `PointerInputScope` also returns `size` which is same `size` unless you set any padding or other layout modifiers after that.

And if you wish to reset pointerInputScope you can get screen width and height using a `BoxWithConstraint` as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val width: Dp = maxWidth
        val height: Dp = maxHeight

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black)
                .pointerInput(width, height) {
                    
                    // The size you get from PointerInputScope is same as you get from 
                    // DrawScope unless you set padding or another layout modifier
                    
                    val size: IntSize = this.size
                    
                    awaitPointerEventScope {
                        /* track pointers and calculate which
                        keys are pressed using the values of
                        width and height */
                    }
                }
        ) {
            
            val size = this.size
            println("size: $size")
            
            /* draw the piano keys, using the values
            of size.width and size.height to size and
            position them */
        }
        
    }
}
```

2- Canvas is a Spacer with Modifier.drawBehind, anything you do in this scope calls only draw phase of composition which is advised by google, especially for animations.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads

Check out background animation snippet.